# How do you get the map to Pan using ui-angiular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, leaflet, ui-leaflet

I'm using ui-angular but I'm I cant figure out how to get the map to panTo a new location. I understand how it would work it I was just using Leaflet.js but because this is a directive I don't understand what object I'm supposed to use to interactie with map on the page.

```
Here is my map directive
<leaflet id="owmMap" center="center" markers="markers" layers="layers"></leaflet>

 Here is my code so far.

  $scope.moveTo = function(obj){
        console.log(obj);

      //map.panTo((new L.LatLng(40.737, -73.923));); <--- This is what I need to replicate
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, like most things the answer was buried in the documentation. For some reason there are actually 3 different sites for this plugin with different set of docs, but I found the answer on the git repo.

https://github.com/tombatossals/angular-leaflet-directive

If anyone else has this question.

There is a data object called "leafletData" that you can pass into your 'Controller' and use to access the map object directly on the page.
Here is some sample code:

```
 $scope.moveTo = function(obj){
      leafletData.getMap('myMap').then(function(map) {
         map.panTo({lat: obj.lat, lng: obj.lng});
       });   
 }
```

Comment: Notice the map object is returned in a form of a promise (from [the docs](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-leaflet)).

Comment: Yeah I noticed that, but I'll be honest, I wasn't sure what the benefit was or how I could use it otherwise.